# How to remove duplicate/contain from array in PHP

Tags: php

I have array set in php. I need to remove duplicate/contain record from below code.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [percent] => 88.461538461538 [basenum] => 079 [code] => HL [group] => 0 )
    [1] => Array ( [percent] => 88.461538461538 [basenum] => 097 [code] => HL [group] => 0 )
    [2] => Array ( [percent] => 88.461538461538 [basenum] => 709 [code] => HL [group] => 0 )
    [3] => Array ( [percent] => 88.461538461538 [basenum] => 790 [code] => HL [group] => 0 )
    [4] => Array ( [percent] => 88.461538461538 [basenum] => 907 [code] => HL [group] => 0 )
    [5] => Array ( [percent] => 88.461538461538 [basenum] => 907 [code] => TL [group] => 0 ) // This will not removed because of 'code' different in array
    [6] => Array ( [percent] => 88.461538461538 [basenum] => 907 [code] => HL [group] => 1 ) // This will not removed because of 'group' different in array
))
```

Element 1,2,3,4,5 will be removed because of `basenum` contain in element 0. So the expected result/new array should be

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [percent] => 88.461538461538 [basenum] => 079 [code] => HL [group] => 0 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [percent] => 88.461538461538 [basenum] => 907 [code] => TL [group] => 0 )
    [2] => Array ( [percent] => 88.461538461538 [basenum] => 907 [code] => HL [group] => 1 )
)
```

Thanks for all answer.

Comment: check this out, https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_array.asp

Comment: Link does not help much.

Comment: You can simply use a for-loop to check whether the `basenum` exists already, if yes, skip to next; if not, add to a `$result` array. It shouldn't be difficult. You can use `array_map()` as well, but it's far more complicated.

Comment: Hi Raptor, Thanks for idea.

Comment: How does `079` = `097` or `709` or `790`?

Comment: 079=097=790=709=907=970. So, only 079 need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `basenum` values are equivalent if they contain the same set of characters, this code will do what you want. `compare_basenum` checks if two `basenum` values are the same by sorting the characters in each of them and comparing the resultant arrays. In the loop, we look at all the values with matching basenums and see if the `code` or `group` values are the same, if not, we add that value to the output.

```
function compare_basenum($b1, $b2) {
    $b1 = str_split($b1);
    sort($b1);
    $b2 = str_split($b2);
    sort($b2);
    return $b1 === $b2;
}

$newdata = array();
foreach ($data as $d) {
    $matching_basenums = array_filter($newdata, function ($v) use ($d) { return compare_basenum($v['basenum'], $d['basenum']); });
    if (!count($matching_basenums) || 
        !in_array($d['code'], array_column($matching_basenums, 'code')) || 
        !in_array($d['group'], array_column($matching_basenums, 'group'))) {
        $newdata[] = $d;
    }
}
print_r($newdata);
```

Output (for updated data based on OPs comments below):

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [percent] => 88.461538461538 [basenum] => 079 [code] => HL [group] => 8 )
    [1] => Array ( [percent] => 88.461538461538 [basenum] => 709 [code] => HL [group] => 0 )
    [2] => Array ( [percent] => 88.461538461538 [basenum] => 907 [code] => TL [group] => 0 )
    [3] => Array ( [percent] => 88.461538461538 [basenum] => 907 [code] => HL [group] => 1 ) 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/6FZZ3)

Comment: This does not work once I try adding more group e.g. group 4, 5

Comment: Can you show me some sample data which it doesn't work for?

Comment: Hi Nick, From demo link, Could you pls change 'group' of first 2 record from '0' to '8'. Then you'll see result.

Comment: @Chaiwat Jo You should not downvote simply because your sample data is incomplete

Comment: No, I never devote any comment. Pls check who did that?.

Comment: @ChaiwatJo I've updated my answer based on your suggested changes to the demo data.

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen I don't think it was Chaitwat Jo, it was downvoted before they had a chance to look at it.

Comment: Michael Eugene Yuen, I quite serious on devote happened. I really do not know who made that devote.

Comment: Sorry for my assumption!

Comment: Dear Nick, Revised code work great, thank you very much.

Comment: @ChaiwatJo Good to hear.